# send https request nodejs express from another computer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

how can i post / get data from nodejs server using another computer ?

so i'm connecting too computers using ethernet cable ,and  i was able to open the website (react ) but
when i try to post or get data  i get this error ( from the one who's not running the server on )
`POST http://localhost:8080 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` 
the too computer are running on the same network
i replaced localhost with the  local IP address but still same error
i also added my local ip adresse to the app.listen

```
app.listen(PORT,'169.254.xxxx', () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`); //PORT = 8080
});
```

but still getting same problem

Comment: Can you open the Dev Tools in the browser and see if you get an error either in the Console or the Network tab?

Comment: Did you use postman to test it first?

Comment: @davidrv87 i get this err :  POST http://localhost:8080 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: @AvivLo yeah i tried with postman i get : cannot GET

Comment: Can you share a sample of your code? Or the repo?

Comment: Do you have some sort of host-based firewall active? Also, are you running Linux/Windows/macOS?

Comment: @davidrv87 sure https://codepen.io/ahmedglas/pen/OJNGarg

Comment: @AvivLo i disabled my firewall on both pc and both pc are running windows 10

Comment: i'am able to open the react app but when i try to submit data i get this error : ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED PS : both pc are connected with ethernet cable

Comment: What's the IP address of the two machines if you run `ipconfig`? It's internal IP so no worries.

Comment: @AvivLo 169.254.32.16 and 169.254.4.23 (i'm runing the nodejs server on this one)

Comment: Run `netstat -an | find /i "listening"` in the terminal to see if the port is binded to the loopback interface or not

Comment: @AvivLo      TCP    169.254.4.23:8080      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

Comment: Seems like it's not binding to the correct interface. It should be something like 0.0.0.0:8000. Try not passing anything to `app.listen` just do `app.listen(8000)` and run the command again

Comment: i set axios.post(' to myip :8080') and changed the app.listen with postman worked fine

Comment: @AvivLo i guess i have to change all my adr from localhost to my ip adresse , thanks for your help

Comment: Ok. Let us know :)

Comment: it works :)  thank you guys.